# How can a theme define which settings for blocks are available in the block editor?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

A website I maintain uses a self-made theme based on a starter theme (Sage). It was developed in 2016, hence long before the block editor appeared.
Now we want to go away (at least for some posts) from a page-builder to the WP block editor.
I noticed that the recently introduced size settings (padding, margin), that are available for many blocks, are not shown in our installation.
I did some tests and came to the conclusion that the theme is causing this.
I already did some tweaks to the theme (e.g. making it PHP 8.0 ready), so I guess I can do it again.
But I have no clue, how a theme can impact which settings are available for blocks or specif blocks.
Can someone advice how to do it or provide a link to related documentation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define the settings on theme.json. Here are the documentation links that would be of help.

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/theme-json/